# Tricky nested list XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT and a bit confused about formating lists. Basicly I need my XML structure, there's a part of it:

```
<slideshow>
    <slide id="A1">
        <title>XML techniques</title>
        <paragraph> Slideshow prepresents different kind of <bold>XML</bold> techniques </paragraph>
        <paragraph> Most common XML Techniques are </paragraph>
        <numberedlist>
            <item> Basic XML, DTD (version 1.0) </item>
            <item> XHTML </item>
            <itemizedlist>
                <item> XHTML 1.0 </item>
                <item> XHTML basic </item>
                <numberedlist>
                    <item> for mobile phones </item>
                    <item> basic set for all XHTML documents</item>
                </numberedlist>
            </itemizedlist>
            <item> XML namespace </item>
            <item> XSL </item>
            <itemizedlist>
                <item> XSLT - template based programming language</item>
                <item> XSL-FO - formating output like CSS </item>
            </itemizedlist>

            <item> Programming API (like SAX and DOM) </item>
            <item> XML Schemas </item>
        </numberedlist>
    </slide>
..
</slideshow>
```

To look like this:

1. Basic XML, DTD (version 1.0)

   - XHTML 1.0
   - XHTML basics

     1. for mobile phones
     2. basic set for all XHTML documents
2. XHTML
3. XML namespace
4. XSL

   - XSLT - template based programming language
   - XSL-FO - formatting output like CSS
5. Programming API (like SAX and DOM)
6. XML Schemas

I wanted to do this as simple as possible, so I was just using templates and no complicated XPath masks, but seems like there's no simply way.. Could someone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is trivial in XSLT, due to it's recursive [processing model](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Processing-Model).

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="numberedlist">
    <ol>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="itemizedlist">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<ol>
   <li> Basic XML, DTD (version 1.0) </li>
   <li> XHTML </li>
   <ul>
      <li> XHTML 1.0 </li>
      <li> XHTML basic </li>
      <ol>
         <li> for mobile phones </li>
         <li> basic set for all XHTML documents</li>
      </ol>
   </ul>
   <li> XML namespace </li>
   <li> XSL </li>
   <ul>
      <li> XSLT - template based programming language</li>
      <li> XSL-FO - formating output like CSS </li>
   </ul>
   <li> Programming API (like SAX and DOM) </li>
   <li> XML Schemas </li>
</ol>
```

**rendered:**

[image]

Comment: To generate valid HTML, I think a bit more work is needed as HTML does not allow a `ul` element as a child of a `ol` element, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element or http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#h-10.2. So the input structure cannot be mapped directly to a valid HTML structure, you would need to make sure the `ul` elements are put as children of a `li` element transformed from a preceding `item` element.